# Is possible edit file on gcp persistent disk?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have node on google kubernetes engine using persistent volume. Is possible edit files on this volume from gcloud, or google cloud shell? For example edit config and recreate node? Or it is only posiible from running pod using kubectl exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can have a look to gsutil command it allows you to interact with your buckets .
[Guide to Gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil)

Answer (score 1):

The volume would be a block device, so I’d expect it’d not be possible to edit it outside of the pod it’s attached to. So yes, expecting into the pod would do it, but you could also just use `kubectl cp` to copy files (and directories!) directly from your local machine onto the volume, mounted to the pod.

Here’s the relevant doc:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp

Comment: I would like find another way to do it, tah via running pod. I would like prepare some confs on persistent file before running container (like using volumes with scripts in docker).